# JPA - Mapping entity to more than one other entity

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, orm, polymorphism

I have two Entities that can be commented by user (lets say for example: news and articles). Is it possible to use one Comment Entity and attach them to the both entities?

I tried it by creating an abstract super class (`AbstractCommentableEntity`), that handles the relationship to the comments (would be `CommentabeEntity1` and `CommentabeEntity2`). The news and article entities then would extend this class and it would be possible to attach comments to them. See my image as well as my code.

But if I implement it like that, I get an Mapping exception. I think thats because I try to map a @MappedSuperclass annotated class. Is there any way how I can get this running?

[image]

My comment entiy would look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

    private AbstractCommentableEntity commentableEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    public AbstractCommentableEntity getCommentableEntity() {
        return commentableEntity;
    }

    public void setCommentableEntity(AbstractCommentableEntity commentableEntity) {
        this.commentableEntity = commentableEntity;
    }
}
```

The abstract superclass for the commentable entities would look like:

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public abstract class AbstractCommentableEntity {

    Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "commentableEntity")
    public Set<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

And a specific entity would just extend it like that:

```
public class CommentabeEntity2 extends AbstractCommentableEntity{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make the association bidirectional: a comment would thus be a general-purpose entity, that can be attached to any kind of entity. The `News` and `Article` entities would both have a collection of comments.

By default, this would be mapped using two join tables: one linking Comment and News, and another one linking Comment and Article.

If you really want the association to be bidirectional, then you could use an `AbstractComment` entity, with two sub-entities: `NewsComment` and `ArticleComment`. `NewsComment` would have a bidirectional ManyToOne association with `News`, and `ArticleComment` would have a bidirectional ManyToOne association with `Article`.